# Spring Boot Hystrix fallback method not being invoked after timeout limit

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit, mockito, hystrix

I want a fallback method to be invoked after a service takes more than 350 milliseconds to complete. Even after 10,000 milliseconds, the method is still not invoked.

I'm running a JUnit test that uses Mockito.

```
UnitTesting.java
...
@Test
public void test1() {

    when(service.getId()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {
               public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 return -1;
    }});
    LateralService latService= new LateralService(service); 
    ArrayList<IdService> returnedIdServices = latService.getIdServices(); //getId() is invoked in this method
    ...
}

LateralService.java
...
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "fallback",
                commandKey = "fallback",
                fallbackMethod = "idServiceFallBack",
                commandProperties = {
                   @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "350")})
public ArrayList<IdService> getIdServices() {
    int id = service.getId();

    ...
}

public ArrayList<IdService> idServiceFallBack(){
    return new ArrayList<IdService>() { add(new IdService(1)) }
}
```

Comment: Refer to this solution [Hystrix Circuit Breaker test configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781398/test-drive-hystrix-circuit-breaker-configuration)